# Excel VBA Nested Loop Efficiency

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, nested-loops

I am looking to increase the speed of this Excel VBA Nested Loop.  The loop compares dates from one sheet to a secondary sheet.  If they match, I change the border around the cell to highlight it.  It currently works fine, but takes about 30 seconds to process per sub. Is there a way to implement an array or other tactic to speed it up?  Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Single()

Dim DateRng As Range, DateCell As Range, DateRngPay As Range
Dim cellA As Range
Dim cellB As Range
Dim myColor As Variant

Set DateRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SS").Range("B11:F16,I11:M16,P11:t16,B19:F24,I19:M24,P19:t24,B27:F32,I27:M32,P27:t32,B35:F40,I35:M40,P35:t40")
Set DateRngPay = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PS").Range("C2:C67")
myColor = Array("38")

If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("B67") = 1 Then
    With DateRng
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            '.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders.ColorIndex = 1
            .Borders.Weight = xlHairline
    For Each cellA In DateRng
        For Each cellB In DateRngPay
                If cellB.Value > "" And cellA.Value > "" And cellB.Value = cellA.Value Then
                With cellA.Borders
                    .ColorIndex = myColor
                    .Weight = xlMedium
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cellB
    Next cellA
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If this works and you want to make it faster it should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as it is not on topic for this forum.

Comment: Message me if you'd like as I don't check codereview as often. Arrays for sure.

Comment: Using a dictionary to hold data from one sheet for comparison with data from another is a standard VBA trick for converting quadratic algorithms to linear ones. My guess is that you should be able to reduce the 30 seconds to a fraction of a second.

Comment: Perhaps you could just use `Conditional Formatting`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Nah -- too simple. If you let too many people know about that, VBA programmers might find it harder to make a living.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm not getting notifications of comments for some reason... Scott, I'll post to codereview also (didn't even know about it lol)... John, I'll research the dictionary, it may work well as a single reference.  Ron, I'm looking for a little more flexibility than conditional.  The code is actually a bit longer, I just narrowed it down to the meat and potatoes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` on top of your code and then `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the bottom? It disables screen updating and my macros go **a lot** faster. There are also other settings you can disable (and then re-enable), see for example [this website](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/ten-things-you-can-do-to-speed-up-your-excel-vba-code/).

---

Update after comment of OP that `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` didn't improve the speed:

I changed your code a little bit and saw some speed improvement. Your code usually took around 0.65 seconds to complete, mine did around 0.51 seconds. Does this code speed things up for you?

```
Sub SingleIsAnIdentifier_SoItCannotBeUsedAsASubName()

Dim DateRng As Range, DateCell As Range, DateRngPay As Range
Dim cellA As Range
Dim cellB As Range
Dim myColor As Integer

Dim RngToColor As Range 'Range to hold all cells to give a colored border.

Set DateRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SS").Range("B11:F16,I11:M16,P11:t16,B19:F24,I19:M24,P19:t24,B27:F32,I27:M32,P27:t32,B35:F40,I35:M40,P35:t40")
Set DateRngPay = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PS").Range("C2:C67")
myColor = 38

If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Info").Range("B67") = 1 Then
    With DateRng
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            '.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders.ColorIndex = 1
            .Borders.Weight = xlHairline
    End With
    For Each cellA In DateRng
        For Each cellB In DateRngPay
            If cellB.Value > "" And cellA.Value > "" And cellB.Value = cellA.Value Then

                ' Add cellA to the range. The range will be colored later.
                If Not RngToColor Is Nothing Then
                    Set RngToColor = Union(RngToColor, cellA)
                Else
                    Set RngToColor = cellA
                End If

            End If
        Next cellB
    Next cellA
End If

' Color all cells in the range.
With RngToColor.Cells.Borders
    .ColorIndex = myColor
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With

End Sub
```

Instead of immediately coloring the border of `cellA` when `cellA.value = cellB.value`, I saved `cellA` in another range (`RngToColor`). At the end of the code I colored all borders in that range. Also, `Dim myColor As Variant` and later `myColor = Array("38")` didn't work for me (`.ColorIndex = myColor` was complaining), so I changed it to an `Integer`.

Comment: I have and unfortunately there was no improvement.